# Async/Await and multi-layer web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await

Because of some optimalization issues, i decided to rewrite controller's action method to asynchronous one. It is a multi-layer application, and since that, i'm facing an architecture problem, and i wonder what are the main differences between two approches I will show below. Let's say my synchronous method is:

```
public virtual ActionResult Method()
{
   SomeLogic.LargeOperation();
   return View(...);
}
```

LargeOpertation does a lot. Here's pseudocode:

```
public void LargeOpertion() {
   DatabaseManipulations1();
   IndependentWork();
   CallingToWebService1();
   IndependentWork();    
   DatabaseManipulations2();
   IndependentWork();
   CallingToWebService2();
   IndependentWork(); 
}
```

Each method inside LargeOperations has couple methods inside itself, and so on ... The question is: Do I need to make them all async and use await in almost every of application layer?

```
public virtual Task<ActionResult> Method()
{
   await SomeLogic.LargeOperation();
   return View(...);
}

public async Task LargeOpertion() {
   await DatabaseManipulations1();
   IndependentWork();
   await CallingToWebService1();
   IndependentWork();    
   await DatabaseManipulations2();
   IndependentWork();
   await CallingToWebService2();
   IndependentWork(); 
}
```

Or can I just use task on LargeOpertaion like that:

```
public virtual Task<ActionResult> Method()
{
   await Task.Run(() => SomeLogic.LargeOperation());
   return View(...);
}
```

Let's also assume that IndependentWork() is not so large.

Comment: How long is /long/ Are we talking minutes? 1 second? hours?

Comment: If `LargeOperation` is asynchronous, the let it return `Task` otherwise use `Task.Run(() => SomeLogic.LargeOperation());`. Other than that I don't understand your question.

Comment: Let's say that there is an operations in CallingToWebService1 that can last around 2 mins, and in DatabaseManipulations1(), DatabaseManipulations2(), CallingToWebService2() 1 min

Comment: LargeOperation is complex. It contains many WebServiceCalls, Database operations. I dont know whether I shoud use Task.Run and async/await in deeper layer (and await it till controler layer) or just use Task.Run in controller.

Comment: You do understand that calling wait after each method is superfluous, your still doing everything synchronous.  `LargeOpertion` should call each method async and then wait for all those to finish

Comment: `Task.Run` will hurt performance as it's jumping into another thread poll thread just for releasing the current thread to the thread pool, thus paying the cost for no benefit. If you have a lot of asynchronous IO, then you should use `async-await` in order to improve overall performance and responsiveness but don't do async over sync.

Comment: So I should start with the deepest layer, and there, use Task.Run only when nessesary. Then, return tasks (or when impossible - await them) till controler layer and await LargeOperation in Controller Layer rather than use await Task.Run(...) on whole method?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "optimization issues"? Are you trying to make LargeOperation run faster, or are you trying to improve the application's concurrency by tying up fewer resources while LargeOperation is running?

Answer (score 4):

> Because of some optimalization issues, i decided to rewrite controller's action method to asynchronous one.

Before you start, you should realize what `async` will do for you *and what it won't*.

Asynchronous operations do not run faster. So, an asynchronous call to the database is not any faster than a synchronous call to the database.

`await` doesn't return to the browser early. All it does is release the current thread back to the ASP.NET threadpool.

So, each individual request still takes the same total amount of time (actually, just slightly *longer*, but not by a detectable amount).

What `async` *does* help with is scalability - that is, the ability of your application to handle more requests with the same resources. However, it only helps the scalability of your *web app* - it can't magically reach into your database and make *that* scale. So, if your scalability bottleneck is your database and not ASP.NET (which is usually the case), then `async` won't help you at all.

**If** your database backend is scalable (e.g., NoSQL, Azure SQL, or a database cluster), and **if** your ASP.NET app needs to scale up, then you can benefit from `async`.

> Do I need to make them all async and use await in almost every of application layer?

The best approach is to start at the "leaves" - the lowest-level methods - and work your way up from there. In this case, start at the database interaction and convert those to `async` first.

However, at no point should you use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. Instead, use true asynchronous APIs, such as the `async` support in EF6.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to use Task.Run at some point, because I use api that doesn't have async support (in case of EF of course I can use their async support). Hence, I do have doubts where should I use it, since I need it anyway. Could you explain why starting with leaves is the best approach?

Comment: @user3558203: There's no point in using `Task.Run` on ASP.NET. It won't help you scale.